# WooCommerce Prevent Formatting digital links

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce, urlencode

On **WooCommerce** when I add a **digital link** to a product, after saving the page **the link format is broken**. (erasing the %)

*Example is the original link* (i need to keep)
https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2Fq6gdgL

*And after recording it becomes.*
https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=httpgoo.glq6gdgL

How to keep the formatting of %?
Is there a possibility to change the php source code?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the link like this:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http://goo.gl/q6gdgL
```

You have tried to add your URL encode.
Have a look at [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to understand what I mean.